# Using {\AA} when \r is redefined

Tags: macros, symbols, expansion

I'd like to use `{\AA}` to input a [capital A with a ring above](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c5/index.htm). However, the document I am writing has to import some definitions which I have no control over.

One of the definitions changes `\r`:

```
\renewcommand{\r}[1]{\right#1}
```

Is there a way to import the above definition without changing it, and somehow still use `{\AA}`? I can put definitions before the file that changes `\r` is imported, if that helps.

Comment: One of the silliest redefinitions I've seen, you have all my sympathy 

Comment: Isn't as simple to use utf8 inputenc and simply type Å?

Comment: @Bernard: actually... it seems the redefinition of `\r`, on its own, is enough to break `Å` (with either `utf8` or `utf8x`).

Comment: @Bernard it's simple to type Å but it doesn't work if someone loads a package that breaks latex internals.

Comment: @Bernard but that is the point of this question, a case where `\r` has been redefined.

Comment: @egreg It is not silly redefinition. It is very natural to use short names as `\r`. A avarage user cannot expected that this control sequence is a part of LICR (LaTeX Internal Character Representation). Silly is LaTeX itself because it uses such "natural" control sequences in its internals.

Comment: @wipet I beg to disagree; `\AA` is a traditional replacement for `\r{A}`. Remember that LaTeX predates Unicode input and I'm ready to bet that no Czech user would like a complicated macro name for the ring accent. *All* accent macros have simple names.

Comment: @wipet -- but knuth used so many of the single-letter commands to denote accents that it's natural to use `\r` to denote the ring (which is needed over letters other than "a"; i'm sure you're familiar with the "u" with ring).  it's really a good idea to avoid (re)defining one-letter commands for any other purpose, no matter how convenient it may seem.

Comment: Of course, all accent macros have simple names, but this is bad decision from today point of view. Nobody writes `\r u` nor `\r{u}` nor `\accent23u` today. We write only `ů`. And today users can be surprised why such simple control sequences are reserved to such unusual things.

Comment: LICR *can* use more protected control sequences than single-letters because it is generated from characters like `ů` automatically. But it does not this. The old control sequences like `\'` `\v` can have default meaning as Knuth decided but they can be redefined without LICR crash. This is the reason why I am saying that LaTeX is silly in this feature.

Comment: @wipet not everybody uses the actual characters for input. I for my part don't even have a clue how to input ů on my keyboard (I copied it from your comment). Using accent macros is much easier IMHO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

whatever is defining `\r` is incorrect and breaking latex so you should report a bug even if you can not change it.

Use `\let\temp\r` before importing the bad definitions and put `\let\r\temp` after them to restore `\r`.

You could of course redefine `\AA` but `\r` is an encoding specific command so it is (re)defined if you switch encodings such as

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

it is used internally if you use Å directly using inputenc, so you would have to make multiple changes in many files to make latex not call `\r` anywhere.

Comment: I hope that LaTeX3 is more flexible in this regard, and that no document command is “fixed”.

Comment: @Manuel The current approach has separate code and document levels, so we would expect something like `\AA` here to be implemented as a code-level command not in terms of another document-level one. (There are complex open questions about engine support and thus the nature of `\AA` specifically, but the general point stands.)